# How to split strings in js with varying length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, decoding

I am building a program to decode a set of strings, where I want it to split in the following order:

```
“ansdl001, badgef001, abcdeh002, mfghe002”

    [ 'ansdl001', 'badgef001', 'abcdeh002', 'mfghe002' ]

    [
       [ 'a', 'n', 's', 'dl', ‘001’ ],
       [ 'b', 'a', 'd', 'gef', ‘001’ ],
       [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'deh', ‘002’ ],
       [ 'm', 'f', 'g', 'he', ‘003’ ]
    ]
```

There is only one way to know when the fourth substring ends, which is before the numbers start. However, I do not have any idea to approach this. We also know that the first three substrings will always be one letter.

I have the following code right now, that splits the strings into one bit strings.

```
let string = "ansdl001,badgef001,abcdeh002,mfghe002";
let array = string.split(",");

console.log(array);

for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {

    array[i] = array[i].split("");

}

array.forEach( (element) => { console.log(element)  } );

/*[
  'a', 'n', 's',
  'd', 'l', '0',
  '0', '1'
]
[
  'b', 'a', 'd',
  'g', 'e', 'f',
  '0', '0', '1'
]
[
  'a', 'b', 'c',
  'd', 'e', 'h',
  '0', '0', '2'
]
[
  'm', 'f', 'g',
  'h', 'e', '0',
  '0', '2'
]
*/
```

How can I separate those two last substrings based on their conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Split into array of strings, note the space next to the comma
const myArr =  "ansdl001, badgef001, abcdeh002, mfghe002".split(", ")

// Loop over the array with .map() so it returns an array
const newArr = myArr.map(str => {

  // Index where the numbers start
  const numIdx = str.length-3
  
  // Get the numbers as a string
  const end = str.substr(numIdx)

  // Get the middle
  const middle = str.slice(3, numIdx)

  // Get the start
  const start = str.slice(0, 3).split("")
  
  // Return in new array
  return [...start, middle, end]
})

newArr.forEach(item => display(item))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, though I am sure it could be refined

```
let string = "ansdl001,badgef001,abcdeh002,mfghe002";
let array = string.split(",");

console.log(array);


let newarrays=[]

array.forEach(el => {
 // get numbers first
 let lastitem = el.match(/\d+/g);
 let tmp = el.split(lastitem)[0];
 let lastletters = tmp.substr(3);
 tmp=tmp.split('');
 newarrays.push([tmp[0], tmp[1], tmp[2], lastletters, lastitem])
})
console.log(newarrays)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following code:

```
let string = "ansdl001,badgef001,abcdeh002,mfghe002";
let array = string.split(",").map(
        el => el.match(/(\D)(\D)(\D)(\D*)(\d*)/).slice(1)
    );

array.forEach( (element) => { console.log(element)  } );
```

Explanation of the RegExp:

- `(\D)` matches the first non-digit
- `(\D)` matches the second non-digit
- `(\D)` matches the third non-digit
- `(\D*)` matches any more non-digits that follow
- `(\d*)` matches any digits in the end

Since `String.match(...)` returns an array beginning with the whole match and then listing the matches of subexpressions, I have to remove the first entry with slice(1).

Note that `slice(...)` copies the array, but using `pop()` would make the code more compilcated.